aws amplify start-job pulling incorrect branch
I am trying setup something in my github actions that triggers a call to aws amplify. It runs:
aws amplify start-job --app-id <app_id> --branch-name pr-626 --job-type RELEASE --query 'jobSummary.jobId' --output text
It does successfully kick the job off but it is checking out my main branch instead of the pr-626 branch. Their documentation states that it should pick up the changes from the specified branch but that isnt the case. Has anyone else had this issue and figured out a work around?
I have tried doing this via github and via the AWS CLI and it is the same problem regardless.
